# Why is filter(str_detect() returning the wrong values using R?

Tags: r, string, filter, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to match people that meet a certain job code, but there's many abbreviations (e.g., "dr." and "dir" are both director. For some reason, my code yields obviously wrong answers (e.g., it retains 'kvp coordinator' in the below example), and I can't figure out what's going on:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test <- tibble(name = c("Corey", "Sibley", "Justin", "Kate", "Ruth", "Phil", "Sara"),
               title = c("kvp coordinator", "manager", "director", "snr dr. of marketing", "drawing expert", "dir of finance", "direct to mail expert"))

test %>%
  filter(str_detect(title, "chief|vp|president|director|dr\\.|dir\\ |dir\\."))
```

In the above example, only Justin, Kate, and Phil should be left, but somehow the filter doesn't drop Corey.

In addition to an answer, if you could explain why I'm getting this bizarre result, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: For debugging regex, tools like [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xd2H5d/1) can make things a lot easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `vp` in `str_detect` pattern matches with `kvp`, that's why you are getting it in the output.

```
test %>% filter(str_detect(title, "chief|\\bvp\\b|president|director|dr\\.|dir\\ |dir\\."))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name   title               
  <chr>  <chr>               
1 Justin director            
2 Kate   snr dr. of marketing
3 Phil   dir of finance
```

Comment: wow, I feel silly. Quick follow up: what does the \\b around vp stand for?

Comment: @J.Sabree, it's a word boundary in regex.